# Unable to connect to database Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Unable to connect to database using these parameters, I uploaded my local project in my cPanel but I didn't make it work.

Error messages:

> {"code":500,"message":"An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)"}

logs:

```
[2017-05-08 10:37:09] request.INFO: Matched route "get_users". {"route":"get_users","route_parameters":{"_controller":"SwipeBundle\\Controller\\Backend\\API\\UserController::getUsersAction","_format":"json","_route":"get_users"},"request_uri":"http://swipe.com.ph/api/users","method":"GET"} []
[2017-05-08 10:37:09] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":3} []
[2017-05-08 10:37:09] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on guard configurator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"SwipeBundle\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-08 10:37:09] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on guard configurator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"SwipeBundle\\Security\\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-08 10:37:09] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on guard configurator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"SwipeBundle\\Security\\AccountLoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2017-05-08 10:37:09] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-05-08 10:37:09] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)" at /home/swipecom/contactless/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 115 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\DriverException(code: 0): An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) at /home/swipecom/contactless/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:115, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2003): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) at /home/swipecom/contactless/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47, PDOException(code: 2003): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) at /home/swipecom/contactless/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43)"} []
```

Parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: com_contactless
    database_user: com_swipe
    database_password: Js121716
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

I've checked the values in `parametes.yml` and I swear they're all correct

Comment: database port is usually 3306

Comment: Probably host is incorrect. Many hosting services have databases on separate machines.

Comment: I update my code please check.

Comment: try localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, see my answer below. try from the command line

Answer (score 1):

The standard MySQL port is 3306, unless you've been told by your provider to use this other port, you should stick to the default.

try connecting manually via the terminal:

```
mysql -uswipecom_swipe -p localhost
```

if you are indeed running on a different port add `-P8889` to the command, you can also select a host by adding `-h` i.e. `-h127.0.0.1`

If this still does not work, ensure that the password is correct and check the user can access from localhost.

Comment: I'm running the application in cpanel. I don't have terminal to check it.

Comment: in cpanel, goto Mysql Databases and check db name, user and access

Comment: I checked the database name, even the username and password but still I cannot connect?

Comment: you may need to log a support ticket with your hosting provider. It seems they have a specific setup judging by the obscure port number your using. All of the required information should be available via cPanel though. Can you access the db via phpMyAdmin and can see the required tables and data?